# Unable to store Date in ISO8601 format for "datetime" data type column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, zend-framework2, wamp64

I am using Zend Framework 2 for Rest API and used the below code to generate a date to store in the DB table having data type "datetime".

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$create_date = $date->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Incorrect datetime value: '2020-08-26T06:16:21+0000' for column 'create_date'
```

I am using WAMP3.19, PHP 7.0.33, and MYSQL 5.7.26

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any solution for this issue so I just switched from WAMP to XAMPP and everything is working fine.